# Is the implementation of Django code into HTML possible?

Tags: python, html, django

HTML File:

```
<script>
from django.contrib import messages
messages.error('Sign-In First')
</script>
```

This doesn't work but is there a way where I can do this?
Because my layout of an error message is not appealing as compared to Django's.

If it's not possible a simple no would do, thanks!

Comment: No. You can only run javascript this way.

Comment: Okay Thanks @HåkenLid

Comment: You have to remember what is executing where.  Python is executing on your server.  The HTML and Javascript are executing in the user's browser.  You can send over HTML to display whatever HTML you need, in whatever format you like.

Comment: If you want to use Django messages framework you must add messages server side. That can be done in a Django view function before rendering the template. If this is for client side error messages, you can use javascript and attach html elements with appropriate css classes that will look just like messages created with Django messages. You should inspect the html produced by Django. In the Django admin site, a message is simply something like this: `<ul class="messagelist"><li class="success">You did it! Go you!</li></ul>`

Comment: I was just researching upon Django messages framework, but as you just clarified it is for client-side error messages so, in fact, I do need JS and HTML. Thank you! @HåkenLid